# Populate form field with data from model without using foreign key

Tags: python, django, forms

My problem is simple to explain but I can only think of hacky ways to solve. I have a list of 800 items that I want the user to be able to pick. They then enter stuff into a text box and hit go.  And then I take it from there and process it and spit a response back.

How do I get the items I have saved in `Taxonomy` to populate in a dropdown in my form?

model:

```
class Taxonomy(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)

    def __str__(self): #python 3.3. is __str__
        return self.specialty
```

view:

```
def NPI(request):
    form = NPIQueryForm(request.POST or None)
    ...other stuff...
```

forms.py:

```
class NPIQueryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Taxonomy
        fields = ['specialty']
```

The hacky ways I've considered is to just create an input field and manually paste the options. But I want them to be easily modified in admin so i'm avoiding that.  Also, I considered creating two models with one being a foreign key of the other but this just seems to be very unnecessary.   I must be missing something.

Comment: What's your actual issue? Too many options to render in the form?

Comment: How do I get the items I have saved in `Taxonomy` to populate in a dropdown in my form?

Comment: Is ModelChoiceField what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: ah yes it is thank you!

Comment: Great :) I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for selecting an option from a list of model objects.

It can be used like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  speciality = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Speciality.objects.all())
```